# Call a method after deploying a war in a Java EE server

Tags: java, class, jakarta-ee

I am deploying two war say A,B in Java EE Server say Jboss.

Deployment order will be

1. WAR A
2. WAR B

I need to call a method once war B is deployed. That method will create an instance of a class which will be loaded only from the class path mentioned in the manifest file of the war.

I used a **ServletContextListener**, but this failed.

**Note :** I tested ServletContextListener - by specifying a sample content in the static block of the class that has to be instantiated and tried to create an instance from the ServletContextListener. But an error is thrown stating "RunTime Exception unable to load the class", and the sample content is also not displayed. More over the class is loaded in the server which is confirmed via -verbose:class option in the JAVA_OPTS.

But it works if I load the class from war A. It even works fine. It's a big process to explain why there is a need for creating such instances. I don't want to change the way in which the instance of the class is created.

Is there any other way to call the method after the war and all its dependencies are completely loaded?

Comment: Can you include the exact error message you see and part of the stack trace?

Comment: Is the class you want to instantiate in WAR A or WAR B? Do you use EJB?

Comment: No i am not using EJB , The class which want to instantiate is in jar placed in ear/app-inf/lib and referred from WAR B in Manifest

Comment: What version of JBoss are you using?